# Python: Perform ations repeatedly over a time interval, as long as a condition is true

Tags: python, sleep, while-loop

So I'm trying to do this (access a file on a website, read its contents and perform actions until the content says to exit. The precondition being it has to wait x seconds before accessing the website again; to recheck the contents):

```
perform = True
while(perform):
 data = urllib.urlopen('someurl')
 data = data.read()
 if(data == '0'):
  dosomething()
 elif(data == '1'):
  #1 signifies to exit the loop
  perform = False
 else:
  time.sleep(10)
```

However this never seems to work. 'Someurl' always has a value. Some Google says that it's something to do with the sleep function. Please help!

Comment: If you attack the server every ten milliseconds it's quite likely that it'll block you outright within a few seconds (or allowing for reasonable lag in connections, a minute or two before it decides you're a pest). Then you'll get a 503 or something like that. Slow down.

Comment: @Chris Morgan: in Python, time.sleep's argument is in seconds, not milliseconds (and may be a floating-point number). At least in 2.x, anyway.

Comment: @Karl: true. Never having used `time.sleep` myself and being used to such things working in milliseconds from other languages it didn't occur to me it'd use a different unit.

Comment: @Chris: from Python docs: `time.sleep(secs)`: Suspend execution for the given number of seconds, so not milliseconds, but seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this:

```
import time
while True:
    print "fetching"
    time.sleep(10)
```

is the minimal test case and as this always works it can't be a problem with the `time.sleep` function

Comment: Okay, it looks like the issue was specific with the IDE I was using; Wing. The never threw an output, even with the code you provided. However when I run the py file directly, it works perfect. Weird! But thanks anyway :)

Comment: Your IDE is probably buffering output and will show it when program finishes, or buffer will have some amount of data. I think you can write log to some file (and flush that file).

Answer (score 1):

1) Have you tried actually checking what `data` you get back from reading the URL? Like, printing it out or something?

2) If the data does actually match '0' or '1', then you don't get to the `else` case, so the `sleep()` doesn't happen. This is bad because it means you try to read the data again immediately. It probably won't have changed, and web servers usually don't like you very much when you ask them for the same URL over and over without pausing (they think you are trying to hack them). Solution: don't put the `sleep()` call in an `else` case; just leave it at the same level as the original `if`. You don't need an `else` to have valid code.